# Back up of Streaming server

Tags: streaming

I want to take a new streaming server for my website which generally holds videos and audio files. But how do we maintain backup of the streaming server if storage size is increasing day by day.

Generally Database server, like Sql Server, backup can be easily taken and restored very easily as it does not occupy much space for medium range application.

On the other hand how can we take backup of streaming server. If the server fails, the there should be an alternative server / solution that should decrease downtime of the server.

How the back-end architecture of YouTube built to handle this.

Answer (score 1):

The backend architecture of YouTube probably uses Google's BigTable which stores objects redundantly over several different servers.  If you are using a single server solution your only real options are backing up to an attached disk, backing up to another server or using an offsite storage system like Amazon S3 (which you could then use with their CDN to do basic HTTP streaming of content in the case of a failure).